# Get object from another package without initialization

Tags: python, object, package, initialization

I have an object called bw. I need this object in my another package, but I don't want this object have to be re-initialized each time that the import is called because I just want to change a property of the object when I call it.

**The file that has the object that has to be use in the others package (named main.py) :**

```py
bw: BasicWindow = BasicWindow()
```

**A function from another package that need to set a property of the object :**

```py
@staticmethod
def new_profile():
    from main import bw
    from gui.MenuNewProfile import MenuNewProfile
    bw.frame = MenuNewProfile().frame
```

Here in the second code block, the object from main package, bw, is re-initialized.

I saw a lot of post about the concept of setting to `None` and call the constructor in the `if __name__ == "__main__"`. If a do that I have the error that i can't import the object :

```py
bw: BasicWindow


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bw = BasicWindow()
    bw.mainloop()
```

I have also tried the get fonction, but I have the error : `NameError: name 'bw' is not defined` :

**main.py package :**

```py
bw: BasicWindow

def get() -> BasicWindow:
    return bw


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bw = BasicWindow()
    bw.mainloop()
```

**The other package that use the object :**

```
@staticmethod
def new_profile():
    import main
    from gui.MenuNewProfile import MenuNewProfile
    main.get().frame = MenuNewProfile().frame
```